# Snapshots not deleted in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a sonar project with snapshots dating more than a year back. The problem is that old snaphosts are not being deleted, which (I think) causes SonarQube to be really slow. My database cleaner config has all the settings set to default.

When I run the sonar runner from a gradle task, it also outputs this:

```
...
11:23:18.072 DEBUG - Post-jobs : org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob@1cffdfd -> org.sonar.plugins.issueassign.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob@140401 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob@c5f5c2 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob@19261ea
11:23:18.072 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
11:23:18.503 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2014-09-12 and 2014-10-09
11:23:18.507 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2013-10-11 and 2014-09-12
11:23:18.513 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2009-10-16 and 2013-10-11
11:23:18.523 INFO  - -> Delete data prior to: 2009-10-16
11:23:18.524 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects p where p.id=? 
11:23:18.524 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: 1(Long)
11:23:18.526 DEBUG - <==      Total: 1
11:23:18.526 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where scope='PRJ' and root_id=? 
11:23:18.526 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: 1(Long)
11:23:19.191 DEBUG - <==      Total: 186
11:23:19.191 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where scope='PRJ' and root_id=? 
11:23:19.191 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: 2(Long)
11:23:19.192 DEBUG - <==      Total: 0
...
11:23:19.966 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where scope='PRJ' and root_id=? 
11:23:19.966 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: 11658(Long)
11:23:19.967 DEBUG - <==      Total: 0
...
```

This leads me to believe that the project is configured correctly. However, the old data is simply not removed. I cranked up the log level and looked in the sonar.log file, but I see no error messages. However I also don't see any SQL queries which attempt to remove the old snapshots.

SonarQube uses a MySQL database running on the same server.

I'm running SonarQube 4.5 and SonarRunner 2.3

EDIT: here is a screenshot of (a small part of) the snapshots page in Sonar.
[image: screenshot of Sonar snapshots]

In this screenshot, I want to keep only 1 snapshot per week.

Comment: Are you saying that you have more than "one snapshot per week between 2013-10-11 and 2014-09-12" (for example) ?

Comment: Yes. For example, I have 4 snapshots of the 29th of July in 2013.

Comment: Is it possible to run it with verbose flags (either -X/--debug or -Dsonar.verbose=true ) http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Runner

Comment: I updated the sonar runner output. I don't see anything that would indicate a problem. Is there something in specific I should be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that snapshots that include an event [are never deleted](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/History+and+Events#HistoryandEvents-Housekeeping) unless you [remove those events](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/History+and+Events#HistoryandEvents-managinghistory)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, only a couple of the snapshots have an event.

Comment: Could you please provide a snapshot of your project history in SonarQube and highlight the snapshots that you'd like to see deleted?

Comment: A new version for the project is an event. All your snapshots have a  specific version: 398, 399, 400, etc. That's why they are not deleted. My question then: Are 398, 399, etc. really versions of your project? If not, why do you increment this version each time you run a SonarQube analysis?

Comment: Ah I did not realise a new version implied an event. We used the SVN revision as a version, but apparently, this is not the way it is meant to be done. Thank you very much for your assistence!

Comment: You're welcome! Version is supposed to be the actual version of your application: 1.5, 2.3.1, etc. It doesn't change that often. Usually each time you push a new version to production.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I would never have guessed - this is very surprising behavior, imho they have declared a bug to be a feature.